# Website URL not getting updated

Tags: wp-redirect, home-url, shared-hosting

I am using WordPress 4.8.2, and host is GoDaddy (shared hosting).

I developed my client's new website under a sub-directory like so:

http://www.example.com/_new/

I did this so that the old website continues to function under the main URL:

http://www.example.com

I now have to make my website live under this URL. To this end, I backed up the old website's files and directories in another folder, and then moved my own WP files and sub-directories under the main URL, so that my website becomes active.

I next modified the MySQL database entries like so:

```
db> update wp_options set option_value='http://www.example.com' where option_name='siteurl';
db> update wp_options set option_value='http://www.example.com' where option_name='home';
db> update wp_options set option_value='http://www.example.com' where option_name='MBFREE_HOMEURL';
```

Despite this, when I type

http://www.example.com/

it keeps getting re-directed to:

http://www.example.com/_new/

I have placed a simple index.php file in the *_new* folder with the text *hello world* in it, and this is the page that is displayed.

I don't know what I may have missed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it in 2 ways :

1. by adding in .htaccess with your Home Url
2. Place below code in wp-config.php

   define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

Comment: I just tried that; it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you removed baseurl from .htaccess with newer one?

Comment: That did the trick. I commented out the following from .htaccess:

RewriteBase /_new/

Comment: And of course, I started a new browser session to clear the cache. (I was viewing the site in incognito mode so that the sessions are separate.)

Comment: You don't need to comment just keep as  RewriteBase /

Comment: Thanks again. Sub-pages were not working, after uncommenting and rectifying RewriteBase, it worked.